# $(document).ready Not loading external php file into div

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to load an external php file via jquery into a specific div on my index page, but nothing will appear whatsoever.

This is my jquery script in the head

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#content").load("index_content.php");
});
</script>
```

And of course the div is simply called on the page as 
`<div id="content"></div>`

My external php file is nothing special, it's just a table with lots of HTML and a few

```
<?php someFunctionCall(); ?>
```

No matter what I do, the content from the `index_content.php` will **not** load into the page when I load the site

Thanks

Comment: Check your browser's console; are there any errors? Can you see the AJAX `GET` request for `index_content.php` in the _Network_ console tab? What does the response look like? Hint: screenshots of your browser console can help get an answer quicker

Comment: Look at your developer console and enable error reporting for the PHP.

Comment: Ah never mind, I see the issue. See the duplicate link. Next time check your console; you would see _"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"_

Comment: `<?php function(); ?>` that doesn't do anything.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I think OP was just saying there's some function calls

Comment: @Phil Ok. Nice catch (dupe) btw.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I'm aware, it was just a reference to the functions being called in that php file.

Comment: @Phil Ahh, yes I see the error in my ways. The fix was adding `type="text/javascript"` in an independent `<script>` tag surrounding that jquery code. Thanks man

Comment: [`type` is not required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-type), you just needed a separate `<script>`

Comment: @Phil I mean, you're correct, but I swear on all that is good in this world, I had my code **exactly** like this and it didn't work. I truly don't know why it's working now...

Comment: Always have your browser console open when doing front-end work. **Always** 

Comment: @Phil I did I swear! :( There were no console errors, honest lol